# Set a value to intlInputphone input in edit page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have implement international phone number input in my application and it works perfectly ,but i want to set existing phone number to that input box in my edit form.

[image]

Here i want to set my existing phone no to above field.I am tried but value not set.

```
$('#phoneNumber').val($('#hidden_phone').val());
```

here phoneNumber field has automatically generated.I have follow below link
[referal link](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Easy-jQuery-International-Telephone-Input-Plugin-IntlInputPhone.html)

Comment: What issue you are facing, when adding value in phone number field?

Comment: can you provide your html snippet? what is the value of `#hidden_phone`?

Comment: No ,i am not facing any issue when i enter new value it work perfect but here i want show my existing value against an id in edit form.so first i bind phone no in a hidden field and on page load i want to set it.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="hidden_phone" id="hidden_phone" value="<?php echo $details->phone?>"><div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="phone"><?php echo _l('clients_company_phone'); ?></label>
                                    <div class="input-phone"></div>
                                    <div class="text-danger phone_error"></div>
                                </div>

Comment: Please share the complete html and javascript code.

Comment: Yes shivanand ,i have share my html code above and i am already share my javascript code in my post,which is a single line

Comment: i don't see phoneNumber in your html.

Comment: Yes ,this is my edit form so here i want to set my phone no.Have you go through above referal link

Comment: On which event you are setting the value?
Like key up and if the phoneNumber is empty you would like to set the hidden_phone?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201656/discussion-between-shivanand-and-dipti).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you might be trying to set the phoneNumber before it is laoding. 
Replace

```
$('#phoneNumber').val($('#hidden_phone').val());
```

with

```
if ($("#hidden_phone").length) {
    updatePhoneNumber();
}
function updatePhoneNumber()
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ($("#phoneNumber").length) {
            $('#phoneNumber').val($('#hidden_phone').val());
        } else {
            updatePhoneNumber();
        }
    }, 500);
}
```